# Forgot to finish final paper submission in a conference

Tags: publications, conference

I just realised that I forgot to submit the final version of a paper for a conference, and the deadline just passed last week. What should I do in this case? I contacted the publishing office but they said they are not accepting paper submissions.

Comment: Learn from the experience, don't make that mistake again

Comment: quite so..Thank you!but is there any way to save the paper?

Comment: To save the paper, rework and submit to another conference.

Comment: Some conferences accept late papers for first submission (esp. if they do not have enough submissions), but if this is a camera-ready version (is it? What do you mean by "final version"?), it's probably too late.

Comment: yes it's the camera ready version.

Comment: @Ethan Then it's probably over, unless you can sway the editors. If not, treat it as a costly lesson. Anyway, the work is done, modify and send it to some other conference, as Patricia suggested.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Thanks man. My friends told me usually they got remainders from conferences on deadlines, it's a little strange this conference didn't give any..this is not an excuse. the problem is I'm too careless

Comment: @Ethan get yourself some electronic calendar and set the alarm for a few days before important dates - strictly without exception! When reminded, re-set it to one day before the day. That should help, if you *strictly* adhere to it. I found that, once an important date appears in my agenda, email, discussion, etc., I immediately, without regard for decorum, politeness, put it in the calendar [of course, that does not hold when you cross the road, drive a car or similar, but you should not be checking your mail/phone at that time, anyway]. Make it a strict rule, no exceptions.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs that's a great idea, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You're probably out of luck here. You can try to email one of the conference chairs or whoever might be higher up the chain than the publishing office, but that's a bit of a long shot, especially a week after.

I'm so sorry this happened to you. I've come close to missing a deadline once or twice and I now set days worth of reminders just to be sure I don't mess anything up.

Comment: Agreed: it sounds like once the mistake was made, the OP did the right thing to try to salvage the situation, but the situation was no longer salvageable.